# Python вложенные циклы

Tags: python, циклы

Программа принимает целые числа A, B (A < B). Нужно вывести число А B раз, число А+1 B-1 раз, A+2 B-2 раза и т.д, пока A+N не будет равен B. К примеру: A = 2, B = 5
Вывод:
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5
Вот то что я сделал

```
a = int(input("a = "))
b = int(input("b = "))
value = 1
for i in range(a,b + 1):
    for b in range(0, value):
        print(i, end=" ")
    print()
    value += 1
```

Но он выводит:

```
a = 1
b = 5
1 
2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вы же своими руками счетчик увеличиваете. Достаточно начальное значение задать b, и уменьшать его.

```
 value = b
 ....
      value -=1
```

Кроме того, можно обойтись вообще без value, вычисляя границу цикла из a,b,i

Comment: большое спасибо, нужно мне быть вниметельней

Comment: @Юныйпрограммист, не надо удалять вопросы. Лучше ответ прими нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: а ну я чтобы меня не забанили удалил

Comment: @Юный программист Ответы других участников на ваш вопрос- это определённый труд, и уничтожать его как-то неправильно...   [И прочитайте это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: все понял извиняюсь

Comment: Видимо - не всё... Если ответ решил проблему, то его стоит принять, как написано по моей ссылке, поставив галочку.